# Elasticsearch MultiSearchRequestBuilder

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have written a query and want to set index on each query execution dynamically. How can I pass the index name.

```
MultiSearchRequestBuilder multiSearchRequestBuilder = null;
 multiSearchRequestBuilder = client.prepareMultiSearch()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build one `SearchRequest` per request you want to make on any index of your choice and then add that `SearchRequest` to `MultiSearchRequestBuilder`

```
SearchRequest searchRequest1 = new SearchRequest("index1"); 
multiSearchRequestBuilder.add(searchRequest1);
SearchRequest searchRequest2 = new SearchRequest("index2"); 
multiSearchRequestBuilder.add(searchRequest2);
```